# How Can I write a gradle script that does commits the current branch on succesful build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have a project and would like to be able to revert to the last successful build on demand. In case I make a mess that breaks the current branch I can have a clear visual of the latest working branch than having to confine that information in mind since as project becomes bigger this becomes quite a tedious process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gradle-svn-tools plugin to provide a way to commit:

https://github.com/martoe/gradle-svntools-plugin

This plugin provides an svnCommit task: 
https://github.com/martoe/gradle-svntools-plugin/blob/master/docs/SvnCommit.md

```
plugins {
id "at.bxm.svntools" version "3.0"
}

task myCommit(type: at.bxm.gradleplugins.svntools.tasks.SvnCommit ) {
  source << project.file("src/main/java")
  commitMessage = "Committed version ${version}"
  recursive = true
}

commit.dependsOn test
```

For git you can use this plugin, though I haven't tried it, as I tend to use subversion:
https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git-publish

If you use a combination of dependsOn and finalizedBy.  The task will only run if the thing it dependsOn succeeds. For example:

```
task myTask {
    doLast {
        println "This task actually happened"
    }
}

myTask.dependsOn test
check.finalizedBy myTask
```

Failure when run check:

```
Gradle Tasks: check

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses

> Task :test FAILED

TEST.LibraryTest > testSomeLibraryMethod FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at LibraryTest.java:12

1 test completed, 1 failed
```

Success:

```
Gradle Tasks: check

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test
> Task :check

> Task :myTask
This task actually happened

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Comment: I am using git...
Not sure on SVN working with git
And I am trying to automate commits. Not all commits just once a build is completed and if the build is successful then the task should auto-commit the changes made

Comment: If you use dependsOn instead then, the commit task won't run unless the first one succeeds. I just tested it.

you can also use this plugin, although I haven't tried it:
https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git-publish

Comment: Sorry a combination of finalizedBy and dependsOn. Should explain myself better!